# How to change value of object c++ in a function

Tags: c++, opencv

I made the following class:

```
class Data
{
    private:
        cv::Mat image;
        int n;
    public:
        void set(cv::Mat x,int y)
        {
            this->image = x;
            this->n = y;
        }
        cv::Mat get_image(void){return this->image;}
        int get_n(void){return this->n;}
};
```

Inside the main function, I create an object of the class Data, and I need to pass it inside two functions as void pointers:

```
Data data;
data.set(img, number, 0);
function_0((void*)&data);
function_1((void*)&data);
```

The problem is that I can't change properly the values of fields of the object data.
For example, in the function_0 i do something like this, but the object data doesnt change from the initial value.

```
static void function_0(void* userdata)
{
    Data data = *(Data*) userdata; 

    // something

    data.set(img_0, number_0);
}
```

Comment: You have to refer to original object, you can do it by `Data& data = ...`

Comment: thanks its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a reference, otherwise you are making a copy of your data object and changing the copy.

```
static void function_0(void* userdata)
{
    Data& data = *(Data*) userdata; 

    // something

    data.set(img_0, number_0);
}
```